# Selecting specific entities to model in EF

Tags: entity-framework

So When I use the EF wizard right now and choose a view, it creates entities for every column in the view. How can I select entity generation for a specific few columns? I don't need all of them. Also, the DB schema changes often. Anything I can do to make sure it doesn't break my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked two questions, so this will be a two-part answer.

[Answer 1] There is no way to choose specific columns when generating the model via the wizard. However, once the model is generated, deleting a property will remove it (and its mapping) from the model. (Note that non-nullable columns will need to be surfaced as properties or you will get errors).

[Answer 2] In terms of responding to a schema which changes often, your best bet will to make sure you understand what is going on underneath your model. The EDMX contains 3 sections:

1. The "CSDL" - this is the "conceptual model" where your entity definitions are stored.
2. The "SSDL" - this is the "storage model" which keeps track of the state of your database.
3. The "MSDL" - this defines the mapping between the two.

When your DB schema changes and you run the "update model from database" wizard, your CSDL and SSDL may get out of sync. This is because the SSDL gets updated with the changes, but the CSDL will not (unless you are adding something new). Now, for the most part, this is a good thing, because it will not blow away any changes you've made, so your model will still work with your application logic. But you may see errors due to the changes in the SSDL.

There are a few ways to fix this:

- If the changes to the database were relatively simple (added columns, renamed tables, etc) you might be able to simply redefine your mappings (using the "mapping details" window available in an entity's context menu). This does require some manual work. For instance, if new columns are showing up in the SSDL you'll need to add the corresponding properties yourself. You may even need to re-map an entire entity if your tables get renamed or too many mappings get dropped.
- You can remove affected entities from the model and re-add them using the "update" wizard. This will blow-away any customizations you had made, and might cause some of your application logic to break. But if you are happier responding to database changes by updating your application's code than by mucking around with your entity mappings, this could be another option.
- You can edit the XML manually. The designer isn't perfect for every situation, so if worse comes to worst you can always use the XML editor.

Hope that helps! There may not be a *perfect* solution, but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks Smudge! 

for the first part, will my changes be blown away if I don't "update"?

Also, is there a way to get #2 in an automated way? Right now I have to manually fix it and relaunch my web app. It would be nice to be able to fix this on the fly. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: @Aniket - In #1, you should be able to keep your changes to the entity if you run "update" - this step will update only the SSDL (to keep in-sync with the database) and will not overwrite your changes in the CSDL. So, for instance, properties you've removed should not reappear every time you update.

Comment: In terms of #2, there isn't an automated way to fix your model if it breaks due to schema changes. Imagine this: if it automatically rebuilt your CSDL entities based off of changes to SSDL tables, suddenly the error state would be in your app code, which expects the old CSDL (this could require pretty extensive refactoring). It's the nature of database-first development, and it is safer to keep the old CSDL and leave it up to you to fix the code or the mappings to match the new SSDL.